# Sqlite binding within string literal

Tags: sql, binding, sqlite

Using sqlite3, if my query is

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%x%'`

It will match strings that contain `x`. I want to make `x` a bindable parameter, like:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%x?%'`

However, this does not work since the `''` form a string literal. Is there some way of escaping the `?` within the literal? I understand that I could build the bindable parameter to contain the `%` and then use

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE ?`

but this moves the responsibility into my code in terms of handling SQL injections rather than the bind interface. Is there a nicer solution for this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%' || ? || '%';
```

Comment: It's not just sqlite; `||` is in the SQL standard; Postgres and Oracle follow this.  MySQL and MSSQL use `CONCAT()` and `+` respectively, both are non-standard.