# sqlite LIKE problem in android

Tags: android

Hello i've spent almost 2 hours trying to figure out why the LIKE statement doesn't work and i only get this error: `03-03 11:31:01.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11767): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x89d9f8`

In SQLiteManager it works perfectly like this: `SELECT Word FROM Sign WHERE Word LIKE  'he%';`
But when i try to do it from java it won't work.
Here's is my query, i've tried in a lot of ways with no luck:

```
Cursor cursor = m_db.query(MY_TABLE, new String[] {"rowid","Word"},"Word"+" LIKE '"+" ?"+"%'", new String[]{name}, null, null, null);
```

Any ideas? i'm i doing it wrong or is there a bug?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use selArgs for LIKE such a way. You may try this:

```
Cursor cursor = m_db.query(MY_TABLE, new String[] {"rowid","Word"},"Word"+" LIKE '"+name+"%'", null, null, null, null);
```

EDIT:

OK, if you want be safe from SQL injections, don't use above solution, use this:

```
Cursor cursor = m_db.query(MY_TABLE, new String[] {"rowid","Word"},"Word LIKE '?'", new String[]{name+"%"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: That's right, it worked! is there any explanation for why this is happening with the LIKE statement? Thanks for the answer and have a nice day.

Comment: I think, you just can't use ? with quotes, like you did "Word LIKE '?%'".

Comment: And what about SQL injection?? Jonas answer seems to be better.

Comment: Please don't use this 'solution'. It is vulnerable to SQL Injection. See http://xkcd.com/327/ for a good example.

Comment: Downvote because of SQL injection problem with this solution. Use @Jona solution

Comment: Single quotes around `?` are not necessary.

Comment: in my case i removed quotes : `"Word LIKE ?"`

Comment: @Olsavage , can you please tell me how could an sql be done in your first method, because both seem identical to me

Answer (score 61):

The solution is actually very easy.  Just include the % inside your selectionArgs.

```
String []selectionArgs = {name + "%"});
```

Comment: This works for me. This solution is better than the answer of Olsavage because it's not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Kowlown, can you please tell me how could an sql be done in your Olsavage's method, because both seem identical to me

Comment: @juztcode The answer has been edited with the right way to prevent SQL injection. The 2014 edit is good, and can be used.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I did:

```
String []columns = {"_id", "name"};
String []selectionArgs = {name+"%"};
db.query(true,"mydb",columns,"name LIKE ?",selectionArgs,null,null,null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another -- perhaps cleaner -- solution is to use the `||` operator as described here: [Sqlite binding within string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105463/sqlite-binding-within-string-literal)