# How can I get this SQLite query to work?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

When executing the query below, I get a "Stopped Unexpectedly" error.

I am trying to pull only records that contain `"movie"`, in my `"KEY_TYPE"` column from my android Sql table.

This is what I have right now:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.media_list);
    setTitle(R.string.movie_list);

    mDb.query("records", new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE}, "KEY_TYPE LIKE '%movie%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Please provide a descriptive title.

Comment: Please post more code, the stacktrace and edit the title. Thanks.

Comment: This has been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179563/sqlite-like-problem-in-android/5179749#5179749

Comment: alextsc:

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.media_list);
        setTitle(R.string.movie_list);
        mDb.query("records", new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE}, "KEY_TYPE LIKE '%movie%'", null, null, null, null);
        

I'm working on the "mdb.query" part.

Comment: @Warren: I edited your question to include the code you posted in your comment. You still haven't shown the logcat / stack trace to explain what error you are getting though - "Stopped unexpectedly" will be caused by any number of unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: here is the error roport from log cat when i run the app.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: 08-23 16:28:46.665: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1660): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @MisterSquonk:  08-23 16:28:46.665: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1660):     at com.android.wwarren07.mediapro.Movie.onCreate(Movie.java:32)

Comment: @Warren: Assuming line 32 of `Movie.java` is where you are getting the `NullPointerException`, are you absolutely sure that `mDb` is valid? In other words, are you sure it isn't `null`? BTW, I've voted to reopen this question as the other one deals with a `SQLiteException` and not an NPE.

Comment: Give line 32 of Movie.java. Basically a null pointer exception occur when you do A.B or A.B() and A is null. More generally, in a statement like A.B.C.D.E, something at the left of a dot is null.

Comment: @Warren: Just to correct my last comment above - I meant "Assuming line 32 of `Movie.java` is the line with `mDb.query(...)`...". If it's causing the NPE then check `mDb` has been declared and instantiated correctly befor trying to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like

```
mDb.query("records", new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE}, "KEY_TYPE LIKE '%movie%'", null, null, null, null);
```

The % signs around "movie" tell the SQL engine to search for records that contain the string "movie" somewhere in them.

Comment: @Warren: Could you provide some details about the error?

Comment: when i run my app, i get the process has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again.

Comment: i run DDMS and it's a Runtme error on my mDb.query that I've been trying to get going.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple quoting problem:

```
mDb.query("records", new String[] {MediaDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE}, "KEY_TYPE LIKE '%movie%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: i coppied your exact code and I get the "Stopped Unexpectedly "error.  I just don't see what's going on?

Comment: NONE OF THESE ANSWERS ARE RIGHT.  NO ONE KNOWS WHAT THEY ARE TALKING ABOUT!!!

Comment: If you put in the stack trace from logcat, we could be more helpful