# Android compare string ignore case

Tags: android, string

resultString is the parameter I get from sqlite

```
resultString = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(1));
```

I want to compare ignore case with user input , following is the code I have use. But it doesn't work.

For example, in database, I store a username "George"
When I login, I have to type exactly "George"."george" doesn't work.

Here is my code to compare.

```
if (userName.equalsIgnoreCase(resultString)) {
    return true;
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: This looks like it should work. Have you tried hardcoding the test cases. So above your comparison type userName = "George" and resultString = "george"?

Also can you print out userName and resultString before the comparison in your other cases to make sure there's not extra characters like whitespace?

Comment: I tried to hardcoding as u suggest and  the "if" clause works.Still have no idea what happenning.

Comment: if you're sure you're doing everything right, this is a hail mary, but could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: I would now go through it normally and have it Log.d("TAG","X" + userName + "X Y" + resultString + "Y"); and see if you have your encoding right.

Comment: @nmjohn : when I try to print it out to log, I figure out that my query has problem. my where clause is username=?. So when I type in "george", the result string is empty.Thank you , I was panic and didn't try the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was panic and didn't try the to print out the result.The problem was my query statement.

```
   String whereClause = DatabaseHelper.USER_COL + " name =?";
```

The resultString is always empty unless input is the same as data.

To fix it I follow instruction in this post 
[sqlite LIKE problem in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179563/sqlite-like-problem-in-android)

```
   String whereClause = DatabaseHelper.USER_COL + " LIKE ?";

   userName = userName+"%"
```

Answer (score 8):

Please try following code,

```
if (userName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(resultString.trim())) 
{     
       return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work if the only difference is the case. I suspect you have leading or trailing spaces. Try the following:

```
if (userName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(resultString.trim())) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int Num;
    String answer = et_q7.getText().toString();
    String right_answer = "Air Pollution";
    String right_answer2 = "Air";
    if (answer.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(right_answer.trim()) || answer.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(right_answer2.trim())) {
        Num = 1;
    } else {
        Num = 0;
    }
```