# How to use LIKE clause in query function

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an application which search messages in the inbox based on sender number. Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

    String[] colList = {"address", "body"};

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, colList, null, null,"DATE desc");

    String yz= String.valueOf(c.getCount());
    Toast.makeText(this, yz, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, searchtxt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
            String number=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
            boolean match = number.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchtxt.getText().toString()) != -1; 

            if (match)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String  body= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n" + body);
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    c.close();
}
```

The above code works fine but it retrieves all the messages in the inbox. I want that it should retrieve only those messages which match the sender number. For that I tried a query using LIKE clause, but with that it returns 0 records. What is the correct way of using the LIKE clause. Here is the code that I tried using LIKE

```
String[] colList = {"address", "body"};
String[] argList = {"'%"+searchtxt.getText().toString()+"%'"};
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, colList, "address LIKE ?", argList,"DATE desc");

String yz= String.valueOf(c.getCount());
Toast.makeText(this, yz, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Please help me out....Thank you...

Comment: Maybe you should use ILIKE, which makes the query case insensitive

Comment: Thanx Alptugay....but it dint work..

Answer (score 9):

There is two joker : "%" and "_".

"%" is replacing any string (multiple characters),

"_" is replacing one (and only one) character.

For example :

```
LIKE 'B%'
```

let you find everything which starts with "B". (like "BATMAN");

```
LIKE '%B%'
```

let you find everthing which contains "B". (like "ABBA");

```
LIKE'_B%'
```

let you find everything which contains ONE caracter, then a "B". (like "ABERCROMBIE)".

if you want to retrieve a string which contains "%" or "_", you may use an escape caracter :

```
LIKE '%#_B%' ESCAPE #
```

let you find any strings which contains one "_" followed by a "B". (like "TEST_BATMAN").

I hope that helped.

Al_th

Comment: Thanx Al_th...but i wanted to know how to use LIKE clause in query function.

Comment: I think you might be interested whith that question's first answer if the problem is within the query function : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179563/sqlite-like-problem-in-android .

Answer (score 3):

Try following **EDITED**:

```
String[] argList = {"'%%%%"+searchtxt.getText().toString()+"%%%%'"};//TRY  THIS
                      ^^^^                                  ^^^^  // TRY THIS

Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(smsUri, colList, "address LIKE ?", argList, "DATE");
```

Comment: I havent created any database. I am  retrieveing msgs from the default inbox of android. so in that case db.query cannot be used.

Comment: Thanx for your efforts Chintan...:)
The problem was with the question mark...The updated code goes as follows:

    String arg = "'%"+searchtxt.getText().toString()+"%'";

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, colList, "address LIKE "+arg, null,"DATE desc");

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in my code, and it took me a while to find the correct answer.
What worked for me is what @Arushi gupta wrote in his reply.

Here's my working code, adapted so that the user may perform EXACT search queries or search for values containing the words in the query (AND operator or OR operator). My code uses a CursorLoader, but it's the same as using a ContentResolver for this example:

```
String selection = myDbContract.myDbEntry.getSelectionForGivenKeywordsAndOperator(requested_keyword, "OR"); //Can write "EXACT" / "AND" / "OR"
return new CursorLoader(this, myQueryUri, MY_TABLE_ELEMENTS, selection, null, null);
```

And here is the selection method in the dB contract:

```
        public static String getSelectionForGivenKeywordsAndOperator(String keyword_list, String operator) {

            String returnSQLCommand = null;
            if(keyword_list.length()==0) return returnSQLCommand;

            switch (operator) {
                case "EXACT":
                    returnSQLCommand = COLUMN_KEYWORD + "='" + keyword_list + "'";
                    break;
                default: //operator is "AND" or "OR"
                    List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (keyword_list.contains(" ")) keywords = Arrays.asList(keyword_list.split(" "));
                    else if (keyword_list.contains(",")) keywords = Arrays.asList(keyword_list.split(","));
                    else if (keyword_list.contains(";")) keywords = Arrays.asList(keyword_list.split(";"));
                    else if (keyword_list.contains(".")) keywords = Arrays.asList(keyword_list.split("."));
                    else keywords.add(keyword_list);

                    returnSQLCommand = "'%" + keywords.get(0) + "%'";
                    if (keywords.size()>=1) {
                        returnSQLCommand = COLUMN_KEYWORD + " LIKE '%" + keywords.get(0) + "%'";
                        for (int i = 1; i < keywords.size(); i++) {
                            returnSQLCommand = returnSQLCommand + " " + operator + " " + COLUMN_KEYWORD + " LIKE '%" + keywords.get(i) + "%'";
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return returnSQLCommand;
        }
```

I verified that this code works as planned, you're welcome to try it.