# Retrive specific data in row from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have following table. I fetched this data from JSON and store it to SQLite table. I want to fetch all data from `TABLE_MAC` where meal_id = 12.

```
TABLE_MAC

| _id | meal_id |   name   |
----------------------------
|  1  | 12,16,17| mac veggi|
|  2  | 14,16   | mac allo |
|  3  | 16,12,14| mac egg  |
|  4  | 112,1,14| fries    |
```

Now, from a database, I want to fetch all data from meal_id = 12. I applied `LIKE` operator for fetching data from a database, but it adds `fries` in Android.

Comment: Well, `112` is "like" `12`... Don't store a comma separated list in a single column

Answer (score 3):

Call **LIKE** Operator

```
 public List<Model> getAllResult(String getId)
    {
        List<Model> resultList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        // Select All Query
       String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MAC + " WHERE " + KEY_Meal_ID + " LIKE '%"+getId+"%'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                Model sg = new Model();
                sg.set_id((cursor.getString(0)));
                ......             

                resultList.add(sg);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }

        // return list
        return resultList;
    }
```

Comment: How exactly would this work? `KEY_Meal_ID` doesn't equal `12`, as per the question

Comment: need to use LIKE . wait

Comment: But that's the problem mentioned in the question ;) LIKE doesn't work

Comment: `LIKE '%"+getID+"%'`

Comment: this will take the value of 112 also.

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/11686673/3395198

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to query your database

```
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", "meal_id", "name"};
    String TABLE_NAME = "TABLE_MAC";
    Cursor mCursor =
            database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, columns,
                    "meal_id=12", null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
```

Then you will have to loop through your `Cursor` to retrieve your data.
Having comma separated id's in your `meal_id` column is not a good idea. You should implement a mapping table or rethink your database to avoid this.

Comment: this will returns with 0 rows, because meal_id = "12,16,17" like this in first row